# Conflict of Node versions

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, npm

I have on local Windows node v8.12.0 and npm v6.4.1. On the server I have node v11.10.0 and npm v6.7.0.

I replaced project in server with backup on local machine, but when I type `npm start` I have this error.

```
sh: 1: react-app-rewired: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-01-14T05_41_00_295Z-debug.log
```

Is it possible that project does not start on server due to conflict of node version? If yes, should I upgrade node on local or downgrade node on server?

P.S. I think `chmod -R 777` will NOT solve problem, because other files on server has the same rights and they start with no problem.

P.P.S. there is my package.json file if it`s needed

```
{
  "name": "manager-polling-app-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.4.1",
    "antd": "^3.20.0",
    "arui-feather": "^12.12.0",
    "b64-to-blob": "^1.2.19",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.53",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-awesome-modal": "^2.0.5",
    "react-data-export": "^0.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-export-excel": "^0.5.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-select": "^2.4.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.6.2"
  }
}
```

P.P.P.S. Log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0~prestart: manager-polling-app-                                                                                                                                client@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0~start: manager-polling-app-cli                                                                                                                                ent@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifec                                                                                                                                ycle true
8 verbose lifecycle manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib                                                                                                                                /node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/root/mybpm/manager-po                                                                                                                                lling-app-client/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lo                                                                                                                                cal/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/game                                                                                                                                s:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0~start: CWD: /root/mybpm/man                                                                                                                                ager-polling-app-client
10 silly lifecycle manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-                                                                                                                                app-rewired start' ]
11 silly lifecycle manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 126                                                                                                                                  signal: null
12 info lifecycle manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start s                                                                                                                                cript
13 verbose stack Error: manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewir                                                                                                                                ed start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/np                                                                                                                                m/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/np                                                                                                                                m/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proc                                                                                                                                ess.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /root/mybpm/manager-polling-app-client
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-135-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v11.10.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the manager-polling-app-client@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
```

Comment: yes, its possible to have problems with different node versions, some packages needs to be updated that supports the said version, you need to check the github repository of the packages affected and see if a problem has been reported to it, additionally it would be best to use node versions in the LTS as that version has been out already and most of the packages are already aligned with that version

Comment: Thank you for advice Albert. I will try to update node versione on my local machine.

But interesting is that in past I had node v 8.12.0 on server. I recently updated it accidentally. My second project starts with no problem in server (i suppose, it because it was built with 8.12.0 verison, so if i try to modify it, it will also break?). 

All backups, project were done by 8.12.0. If I update it on local, will it break evverything? Should I downgrade on server first? How do u think.

P.s. I hope I did not confuse you)

Comment: Well you can't stay forever on the low versions of node, so I suggest you start upgrading node versions to the LTS version (not the newest) and fix the problems that will occur, Normally this problems can be fixed easily by looking at the documentations of the affected packages. However, if you really need to deploy your project now you can downgrade the version of the server, im not quite sure how to do it on windows but in mac you can install more than 1 version of node and select it. but dont forget to include on your next update the version upgrade.

Comment: you can also use containers in your programs to simulate the environment of your machine.

Comment: Thanks for reply, my server is on Ubuntu